# Need first two characters from a file and make sure that they both aren't below 6 then return line

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a text file like this

```
17 Blue
45 Purple
```

And I need to make sure the first two digits aren't both less than the number 6 and then print them. So, for example, the first line would print since the first digit 1 is lower than 6 and the second digit 7 is higher than 6, so they aren't both lower than 6. The next line would not print because 4 is lower than 6 and 5 is also lower than 6. I'm trying to use awk and not having any success this is what I have so far. It's just crashing in terminal/bash.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "";} {if ($1 < 6 && $2 < 6) else print}' file.txt
```

I'm using `FS = ""` to separate the first two digits by columns (`$1` and `$2`) not sure if there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: simpler to treat the number as a string: `awk '$1!~/^[0-5][0-5]/{print}'`

Comment: `“”` are "smart quotes", they aren't double quotes as you need for awk `""`. Also, setting FS to the null string is undefined behavior per POSIX so what that does will vary based on your awk implementation.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '!/^[0-5][0-5]/'  file.txt
```

Comment: A small suggestion here, test for the first field. Maybe the first column has a space in front of it.

Comment: Yes, this only works for the OP's description and example as-is. 
Perhaps they will change that.

Answer (score 1):

1 more approach could be.

```
awk -v val="6" 'substr($1,1,1)>val || substr($1,2,1)>val' Input_file
```

Where I am specifically checking either 1st character of 1st field or2nd character of 1st field are more than 6, where I created a variable named `val` whose value I have set to `6` one could change it as per need too.

***About OP's approach:*** Yes, one could set `FS=""` but that will be more specific to GNU `awk` IMHO I don't think so all `awk`s support it, so it may fail if `FS=""` is NOT supported. So it is better to either use `substr` or use regex for this problem(to make solution global supportive).